# SQL execution being so slow on my case

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem about my code, this is my code on connecting to database, selecting some unique data and sum on these unique data from another table, nothing problem with my code, thats all okay, but it taking so long time on querying.

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";

$no=1;
$arqury=odbc_exec($koneksi, "SELECT DISTINCT NIP_AR,NAMA_AR FROM USRBPS.MASTERFILE");
while($ar=odbc_fetch_array($arqury)){
    $total=0;
    $ambilqury=odbc_exec($koneksi, "SELECT NPWP FROM USRBPS.MASTERFILE WHERE NIP_AR='$ar[NIP_AR]'");
    while($ambil=odbc_fetch_array($ambilqury)){
        $testqury=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(jumlah_bayar) as PENERIMAAN FROM mpnruteng WHERE npwp='$ambil[NPWP]'");
        $test=mysql_fetch_array($testqury);
        $total += $test[PENERIMAAN];
    }

    if($ar[NIP_AR]==""){
        echo "<tr><td>$no</td><td colspan=2>UNASSIGN</td><td>$total</td>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<tr><td>$no</td><td>$ar[NAMA_AR]</td><td>$ar[NIP_AR]</td><td>$total</td></tr>";
    }
    $no++;
}

?>
```

on simply is being like this,

```
|Name   |num_se
---------------
|andre  |1111
|john   |2222
|simon  |3333
|andre  |4444
|andre  |5555
|simon  |6666
|john   |7777


|num_se |Total
---------------
|1111   |12
|2222   |15
|3333   |10
|4444   |8
|5555   |20
|6666   |18
|7777   |22
```

So, what i need is get the sum of 'Total', from each 'Name'. What i want to get is, list of the name "Uniquely" (in this example is Andre, John, and Simon) with each sum of "Total" that get from num_se.

sorry my english is bad, but i hope you're understand.

Comment: taht might be taking long time bcoz you may be not having any index,and use joins instead of looping

Comment: do you work with different databases ? in case you don't you can combine your sql into a single query statement which should benefit vastly from the optimized db engine. for the very least iterate over `SELECT NIP_AR, NAMA_AR, NPWP FROM USRBPS.MASTERFILE ORDER BY NIP_AR`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this query may help

```
SELECT t1.Name, sum(t2.Total) 
FROM (table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.num_se = t2.num_se)
GROUP BY t1.Name
```

Modify the table name and column name based on your case.

**Update**

I don't know why you use two separated data source. However, I think this approaches will improve the efficiency of your code.

First, get the list of all `num_se` belong to each `name` by this query:

```
"SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(num_se) as nums FROM table1 GROUP BY Name"
```

Now your result array ('$ar') will have an element like this `"1111,2222"` with the key `nums`

Second, use this query to get the sum for each `name`

```
"SELECT SUM(Total) as total FROM Table2 WHERE num_se IN (" . $ar['nums'] . ")"
```

And you will get the `total` for each `name` without needing a second loop.

Remember to use escaping techniques to be sure your queries is safe.

Comment: but i have a problem, that the 2 table that i have is coming from 2 different type of database, so i cant join it..
the first table from Mysql database, the other is from ODBC Oracle database.
Iam using Apache webserver, appserv.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been pertinent to explain you were working against two separate data sources up front.

It's slow because you're attempting to loop over your resultsets in PHP, calling individual queries to return single rows from another table, which is very inefficient.

Let the database handle the relationship between your two related tables by using a `JOIN` , and then let it handle to aggregation of your grand total, not just the individual totals.

The following query will get your total for each distinct pair of nip_ar and nama_ar:

```
SELECT 
  t1.NIP_AR,
  t1.NAMA_AR,
  SUM(t2.jumlah_bayar) as PENERIMAAN

FROM 
  USRBPS.MASTERFILE t1

  INNER JOIN mpnruteng t2
  ON t2.npwp = t1.npwp

GROUP BY
  1, 2
```

But you're rolling this up into one grand `$total` anyhow, so this will get that for you:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(PENERIMAAN) as PENERIMAAN

FROM 
  (
     SELECT 
       t1.NIP_AR,
       t1.NAMA_AR,
       SUM(t2.jumlah_bayar) as PENERIMAAN

     FROM 
       USRBPS.MASTERFILE t1

       INNER JOIN mpnruteng t2
       ON t2.npwp = t1.npwp

     GROUP BY
       1, 2
  )
```

You can configure a link to your mySql server from your Oracles server. Refer to [Using Heterogenous Service Agents - chapter 4. Setting up access to non-Oracle systems](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14232/admin.htm#sthref152). My understanding is that you cannot link to Oracle from mySql.

This will allow you to run the above queries, on your Oracle instance.  Although you'll need to update your table names to fully qualify them with the datasource names.

Comment: that is okay if i got the database from the same connection, but i get the database with different connection, so I cannot use the inner join..

the one using mysql_connect, and the other using odbc_conect
and both of these using different password and username

Comment: and the format of database query is different between those two, the mysql is using "mysql_query(the query)", but the odbc using "odbc_exec(connection, the query)". so i dont think those two data can be using INNER JOIN. but tell and correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @DymasSedhayu  Did you read the document I referenced explaining how to connect two disparate DBMS together?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, I have noticed that using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 slows down the connection to the database.

Comment: @Sylvain Fabre :
I Already using localhost, but still get this slow

Comment: Then there's something silly going on with the hosts file or DNS configuration on your PC.

Comment: @ArunKillu I don't konw the bottom of this but seems that I'm not the only one: [http://www.borngeek.com/2011/04/05/mysql-performance-and-localhost-performance/]

Answer (score 0):

Before giving any solution I wanted to share the reason why your query is too slow. If you see your code carefully you are opening database connection for reach record in the first query result. The major cost is going in opening and running the query against the database . SO imagine if you have 1000 records in the first result , you will open the database connection 1000 times , that will make it very very slow. Use the Inner join or subquery as stated by Trung . Or if not possible using stored procedure and putting the logic inside the SP will also help you to gain the performance.Create a Stored procedure and pass the input parameter as comma separated Ids what you are getting from another database , Inside the SP use the comma separated Ids to either loop and do the select statement. You can use the temp table to do so. The advantage is that you will open the Database connection only once.

Comment: but i have a problem, that the 2 table that i have is coming from 2 different type of database, so i cant join it..
the first table from Mysql database, the other is from ODBC Oracle database.
Iam using Apache webserver, appserv.

but if you know how to join from this two type of database will be great.

and i'm interesting with your last solution "using stored procedure and putting the logic inside the SP", but i don't really understand, can you please describe it to me?

Comment: I updated my solution. I hope you know how to create Stored procedure in mySQL http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx